# ООП наследование private конструктор родительского класса

Tags: java

почему нельзя наследоваться от класса, который имеет private конструктор, почему класс наследник не может использовать свой конструктор?

Я так понимаю, что класс наследник принимает методы, в том числе и конструкторы от родительского класса, а т.к. модификатор доступа private, то не может принять конструктор родительского класса и соответственно не может создавать экземпляры класса? Спасибо.

Comment: А как наследнику построить класс родителя?  Если у родителя есть хоть один доступный(protected или если пакет тот же - без модификаторов) конструктор - наследуйте на здоровье.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если класс имеет приватный метод, то потомки этого класса не имеют доступа к этом методу. Соответственно, если у класса приватный конструктор, то у потомка нет доступа к этому конструктору. Но конструктор потомка **должен** вызвать конструктор базового класса, чтобы инициализировать структуры базового класса и только затем конструктор может приступить к инициализации своего класса.

Comment: @ktf, ответ понятен, верен и т.п. Но зачем вообще может понадобиться класс только с `private` конструктором? Чтобы использовать его статические методы?

Comment: @andy.37 Не обязательно. Приватный конструктор фактически запрещает создавать экземпляр класса вне класса. Я как-то использовал эту фичу, создавая синглтоны. Статический метод `getInstance` создаёт экземпляр и возвращает ссылку. Но создать этот же класс во второй раз уже нельзя - не даст компилятор.

Comment: спасибо, понял.

Comment: это нужно для создания класса одиночки (singleton), что бы никто кроме его самого не мог создать экземпляр этого класса